# How can I make the wordpress rewrite rules work under a subdirectory?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect certain URLs coming into a wordpress site to another directory outside the document root. It seems the simplest way to do that would be to make wordpress a subdirectory, but then how can I get its rewrite rules to redirect to this subdirectory?

These are the standard  rules in the apache configuration (not .htaccess)

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Since now I want to prepend wordpress to the directory, I changed it as follows

```
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

But I'm getting

```
[perdir /] internal redirect with /wordpress/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

instead. Why? I had initially trying prepending the "wordpress" manually throughtout the rules, but apparently %{REQUEST_FILENAME} stores the initial name and not the rewritten one.

Comment: To clarify, you have physically moved WordPress (and all associated files, including `.htaccess) into that subdirectory? And updated the necessary WP config to include `wordpress` in the URL? If you've done that then there's nothing you need to change about the "standard" `.htaccess` file. "in the apache configuration (not .htaccess)" - what do you mean exactly by "in the apache config" - where exactly? These particular directives won't work outside of a _directory_ context.

Comment: This is another way to do it, but I wanted to see if it could be done with pure rewrite rules and it can. The Apache configuration refers to the virtual host configuration in httpd.conf. The directives I used below in my answer were generating redirect loops when I used a directory context, so I removed it. (RewriteBase requires it, but I ended up not going that route).

Comment: "with pure rewrite rules" - these are all "pure rewrite rules"? If you mean without using `RewriteBase`, then in a _directory_ context `RewriteBase` is a tool you can work with (if necessary), no reason to avoid it. "The Apache configuration refers to the virtual host configuration in httpd.conf" - The directives above would "break" if used directly in the `<VirtualHost>` container - they would need to be in a `<Directory>` container, inside the `<VirtualHost>` - which changes the _context_.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it the way I suggested at the end of my query, not using RewriteBase at all.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /wordpress/index.php [L]
#this rule prepends wordpress to everything
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" /wordpress/$1

#now the files have wordpress prepended, but without directory context, these conditions compare against the whole path 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# we exclude files with wordpress prepended
RewriteRule ^((?!wordpress).*)$ /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

I mentioned briefly that REQUEST_FILENAME wasn't working and I figured out why by upping the LogLevel to rewrite:trace6. It confirmed that REQUEST_FILENAME is getting updated by RewriteRules but without the directory context (that is,   ), it was expecting a full path to the file/directory. So I fixed that by prepending %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} and now the code works.

Comment: If you are using these rules in a _virtualhost_ (or _server_) context then `REQUEST_FILENAME` is the same as `REQUEST_URI` since the rules are processed before the URL is mapped to the filesystem. So, yes, you would need to prepend the document-root to check against the filesystem. OR, use a URL-based lookahead instead, eg. `%{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME}`. However, this does not apply when the directives are used in a _directory_ context (ie. inside a `<Directory>` container or `.htaccess`).

Comment: Note that if used in a _virtualhost_ context, this line: `RewriteRule "^(.*)$" /wordpress/$1` will result in a double-slash after `wordpress` since the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` directive is root-relative (starting with a slash).